# Same help from last post

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

How do I  send email reminders 2 weeks prior to the Lead Date?
Below is my SQL code from a query.

```
SELECT CalibrationRecord.RecordID, CalibrationRecord.CalRequirement, CalibrationRecord.CalStatus, 
CalibrationRecord.CalLocation, Equipment.EquipmentType, Equipment.SerialNo, Equipment.ModelNo, 
Equipment.AssetNo, CalibrationRecord.EmpName, Employees.EmailAddress, CalibrationRecord.LastCalDate, 
CalibrationRecord.CalTimeInterval, CalibrationRecord.UOM,
DateAdd(IIf([CalibrationRecord]![UOM]="days","d",IIf([CalibrationRecord]![UOM]="month","m","yyyy")),
[CalTimeInterval],[LastCalDate]) AS CalUpcomingDate, CalibrationRecord.DateEmailSent, 
DateAdd(IIf([Equipment]![UOM]="weeks","ww"),-[LeadInterval],[CalUpcomingDate]) AS LeadDate
FROM Equipment INNER JOIN (Employees INNER JOIN CalibrationRecord ON Employees.EmpID = CalibrationRecord.EmpName) 
ON Equipment.ItemID = CalibrationRecord.EquipItemID
WHERE (((CalibrationRecord.CalStatus)="Not Started") 
AND ((Employees.EmailAddress) Is Not Null) 
AND ((CalibrationRecord.CalTimeInterval) Between 6 And 9) 
AND ((CalibrationRecord.UOM) Like "month") 
AND ((Employees.EmpName) Not Like "MFGUSER")) OR (((CalibrationRecord.UOM) Like "days"));
```

**This is my Email reminder code. I just want to include a piece of code that will send email reminder 2 weeks prior to the Lead Date.**

```
Function GenerateEmail(MySQL As String)
  On Error GoTo Exit_Function:
  Dim oOutLook As Outlook.Application
  Dim oEmailAddress As MailItem
  Dim MyEmpName As String
  Dim MyEquip As String
  Dim MyModel As String
  Dim MyAsset As String
  Dim MySerial As String
  Dim rs As Recordset
  Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(MySQL)
  If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
   rs.MoveFirst
 Do Until rs.EOF

If Not IsNull(rs!EmailAddress) Then

    ' Only Send Emails if never been sent before - or past 14 days since last one'
     If (IsNull(rs!DateEmailSent)) Or DateDiff("d", rs!DateEmailSent, Date) >= 14 Then

If rs!LeadDate - 2 * 7 <= Date Then **This is what i have so far for the 2 weeks prior to Lead Date**

        If oOutLook Is Nothing Then
            Set oOutLook = New Outlook.Application
        End If
        Set oEmailAddressItem = oOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        With oEmailAddressItem

           'MyEmpName = DLookup("EmpName", "Employees", "[EmpID]= " & rs!EmpName)
            MyEquip = rs!EquipmentType
            MyModel = rs!ModelNo
            MyAsset = rs!AssetNo
            MySerial = rs!SerialNo
            .To = "dgaskins@eeimfg.com"
            .Subject = "Monthly Calibrations"
            .Body = "Calibration ID: " & rs!RecordID & vbCr & _
                    "Location: " & rs!CalLocation & vbCr & _
                   "Requirement: " & rs!CalRequirement & vbCr & _
                   "Name: " & MyEquip & vbCr & _
                   "Serial No.: " & MySerial & vbCr & _
                   "Model No.: " & MyModel & vbCr & _
                   "Asset No.: " & MyAsset & vbCr & _
                   "Upcoming Date: " & rs!CalUpcomingDate & vbCr & vbCr & _
                   "This email is auto generated. Please Do Not Reply!"

        '.Display
        .Send

        ' Make sure to record that reminder was sent '
         rs.Edit
         rs!DateEmailSent = Date
         rs!LeadDate = DateAdd("ww", -2, Now)
         rs.Update
        End With
        ' Only do this if this has been set '
        Set oEmailAddressItem = Nothing
     End If
End If
 End If
 rs.MoveNext
Loop

 ' Do this at end '
 Set oOutLook = Nothing
 Else
 End If
 rs.Close
 Exit_Function:
  Exit Function
  End Function
```

Comment: Hey @dbmitch I made a new question post.

Comment: What does code above do now? Does it do something you don't want it to?

Comment: @dbmitch. the code above sends the email reminders once every two weeks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Get rid of this If and Matching Endif**

```
If DateDiff("d", Date, rs!LeadDate) Then **This is what i have so far for the 2 weeks prior to Lead Date**
```

> **Change this**

```
 ' Only Send Emails if never been sent before - or past 14 days since last one'
 If (IsNull(rs!DateEmailSent)) Or DateDiff("d", rs!DateEmailSent, Date) >= 14 Then
```

> **To This**

```
' Only Send Emails if never been sent before 
' - or past 14 days since last one
' - or with 14 days of LeadDate
 If (IsNull(rs!DateEmailSent)) Or DateDiff("d", rs!DateEmailSent, Date) >= 14 Or DateDiff("d", Date, rs!LeadDate) <= 14 Then
```

Comment: If you scroll down to the bottom I have this line of code `rs!LeadDate = DateAdd("ww", -2, Now)`. Should I get rid of line of code or keep it?

Comment: I'm not sure - what's it supposed to do

Comment: I'm not really sure. So I am going to take this line of code out.

Comment: How do I make the query show only dates that are not past due.

Comment: For the overdue task I want send the user a reminder once every day until the status is complete. How do I create go about doing that?

Comment: This is not at all mentioned in your question - What criteria is used to decide if a task is overdue? " I just want to include a piece of code that will send email reminder 2 weeks prior to the Lead Date."

Comment: Never mind I figure it out already. Thanks. 

How do I create a filter on a form?If a user wants to search for a specific record on a form.

Comment: Do your consider my answer above an answer to your question or useful?

Comment: Use the combo-box wizard - it will build the code for you